# Как сделать sql-запрос так, чтобы он добавил только те элементы, которых нет в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Допустим, мне нужно добавить в таблицу `term` массив слов, которые, возможно, уже есть там.

Можно сделать так - вынуть все значения из `term`, найти разницу между массивом слов из БД и массивом, который нужно добавить, после чего закинуть в БД результирующий массив, но хочется добавить нужные значения за один запрос.

Можно как-то сделать это?

Comment: Если слово будет уникальным ключом - `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что вы подразумеваете под массивом. один столбец с одним словом в каждой строке, или нечто иное?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, именно это - мне нужно добавить в один столбец несколько строк, в каждой строке по одному слову

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо объявить уникальный индекс или сделать первичным ключем поле со "словом", чтобы гарантировать, что дубликат не будет создан даже при сбое в скрипте. Затем, в зависимости от контекста задачи, вы можете выбрать:

- **INSERT IGNORE** - не-добавление того, что не должно быть добавлено. если вставляете пачкой несколько строк, IGNORE спасет от отмены всей операции;
- **INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** - при обнаружении дубля, сработает "запасной вариант" с обновлением только того, что укажете;
- **REPLACE** - фактически делает DELETE и затем INSERT.

Cмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Answer (score 2):

Если добавляется немного слов, то можно так написать:

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT (формируется список слов) X(word,...)
WHERE word NOT IN(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, есть у нас массив со значениями без ключей - `$term = ['a','b','c']`:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '1111', 'term_base');

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($term); $i++){
        $check = $mysqli->query("select * from term where `term`='{$term[$i]}' limit 1");
        $num = $check->num_rows;
          if ($num==0){
              $ins = $mysqli->query("insert into term values (null, '{$term[$i]}')"); 
          }
    }
```

Или сделать это следующим образом:

```
$terms = $mysqli->query("select * term from terms");
$terms = $terms->fetch_all();
$diff = array_diff($terms, $term);

if ($diff){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($diff); $i++){
        $ins = $mysqli->query("insert into term values (null, '{$diff[$i]}')"); 
    }
}
```

Можно модифицировать второй вариант и сделать одним запросом:

```
$sql = null;
if ($diff){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($diff); $i++){
        $sql .= "insert into term values (null, '{$diff[$i]}');"; 
    }
$insert = $mysqli->multi_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Если это UPDATE в БД то зачем мучиться?, если поле повторяется ну и пусть, вы замените все значения, даже если они повторяются.

#### Пример:

есть:

```
1,2,3,4
```

и вы заменяете:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

вы не добавляете!, вы меняете.